# Error al instalar Composer

Tags: php, composer

estoy instalando composer en mi proyecto y al momento de que empieza la instalación sale este error Failed to decode zlib stream.

Busque el causante de este error y vi que hay que cambiar en el php.ini esto zlib.output_compression=Off por on en php.ini.

Lo he hecho y tampoco a servido.

Estoy utilizando windows 10 y instalando composer con el .exe de su pagina oficial

Comment: Según el github de composer, en este [issue](https://github.com/composer/windows-setup/issues/69); refiere que ese error está relacionado con alguna mala confguración de firewall o proxy.

Comment: Desactive el firewall y mi conexión no pasa por un proxy. No entiendo porque me sigue dando el error

Comment: Si no usas poxy, te sugeriría pruebes instalar el composer en otro equipo que use la misma salida a internet asi terminas de descartar problemas de conexión. Yo lo tengo instalado usando el PHP que viene incluído en wamp y sin problemas.